# Colon Causing workflow error

Tags: workflow, error

I've got a some lists and workflows set up for generating posters and emails advertising events in our office. When a list item is created it does two things

1. Generates an email invite (sent to the item creator)
2. Generates a poster

This has thus far been working flawlessly and dramatically reduced a really annoying part of my job - however it seems like if there is a colon in the event title it causes an error in the workflow - once you remove the colon it works again.

Has anyone ever come across this problem before? if so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to validate the special characters:

> Go to the Custom List where you will be validating for the special
>   characters Click on the ribbon "Library Settings " Select "Validation
>   Settings" Click on the Column validation  Paste the following rule
>
> ```
> IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",Title)),TRUE),
> IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",Title)))
> ```
>
> This rule checks for the special characters such as ',', '&', '!', '@'
>   In the User Message section, please mention "Special characters are
>   not allowed"

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/validation-of-special-characters-in-sharepoint-field-columns1

Comment: Is there a way to allow special characters? Sometimes the event titles will need colons to be included.